# Is Bash on Ubuntu on Windows 10 available in the Windows 10 Mobile edition?

Tags: windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

Not sure does the question fits here but does anybody know will it be coming out on Windows 10 Mobile? Would like to have an 'on the go' development platform right on my mobile (and to leverage on the continuum feature).

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by all of Build's videos on Bash topic and all follow-up info there is no intention to bring it to Windows 10 Mobile, at least as for now.